# How can I align content elements under heading elements?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to achieve below alignment by CSS with fixed width, so those two rows would be below each other when they header and content are not in same div?

[image]

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div>Header Text 1</div>
    <div>Header Text 2</div>
    <div>Header Text 3</div>
    <div>Header Text 4</div>
    <div>Header Text 5</div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
    <div>Content 4</div>
    <div>Content 5</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This seems like a bit of an odd structure, surely grouping the title with its associated content would be more practical?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. You need to make an effort and show it. Please revise to update the snippet I created with your CSS.

Comment: You might look into [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: So how do you exactly see that i could wrap up two contents when they are not fit anymore in first row with the CSS grid?

Comment: If the content is tabular, use a [table element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Answer (score -3):

Indeed you can, to more simplify this process you can break the structure of your html code and then style them using ***Flexbox*** ( not necessary, but it's convenient) accordingly.

html

```
  <section>
   <div id="first_row">
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="second_row">
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="third_column">
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
      <div>
         Element
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#first_row {
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
#first_row > div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#second_row {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  height: 90px;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
#second_row > div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#third_column {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#third_column > div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d8t01ypc

Comment: terrible unresponsive solution. A `css-grid` would be more appropiate for simplicity and responsivness. Despite that, the whole concept is flawed and terrible for screen reader support to begin with.